# Python script tool gives IndentationError in ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, arctoolbox, indentationerror

I am trying to use my Python script for Merge in ArcGIS as a tool.
(to use this script in model)

But it occurs an error (below figure).

I don't know what problem is...

1. Python script : work in ArcGIS geoprocessing-python

   ```
   import sys, arcpy, os
    reload(sys)
    from collections import defaultdict as dd

    arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\test2"
    folder = arcpy.env.workspace
    out_folder = r"C:\test1"


    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


    d = dd(list)
    for root, folder, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, file)) and file.endswith('.shp'):
           ##    print(file)
                d[file[:4]].append(os.path.join(root, file))

    #Execute code above then print(d) to make sure its ok before merging
    for group, mergelist in d.items():
        #print(group, mergelist)
        arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=mergelist, output=os.path.join(out_folder, '{}.shp'.format(group)))
   ```

**2. Revised Python script for the custom tool : error**

```
  import sys, os
reload(sys)
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import arcpy
from arcpy import env


inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
env.workspace = inWorkspace

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


d = dd(list)
   for root, inWorkspace, files in os.walk(inWorkspace):
      for file in files:
         if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, file)) and 
                  file.endswith('.shp'):
   ##    print(file)
        d[file[:4]].append(os.path.join(root, file))

  #Execute code above then print(d) to make sure its ok before merging
      for group, mergelist in d.items():
  #print(group, mergelist)
        arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=mergelist, 
      output=os.path.join(outWorkspace, '{}0.shp'.format(group)))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an IndentationError so this is really a Python rather than ArcPy question.

The code below should not throw an IndentationError but I have not examined it against what you are trying to do, so I suggest you use it to just get past where you are currently stuck:

```
import sys, os
reload(sys)
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

inWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
outWorkspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
env.workspace = inWorkspace

sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

d = dd(list)
for root, inWorkspace, files in os.walk(inWorkspace):
    for file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, file)) and file.endswith('.shp'):
            ##    print(file)
            d[file[:4]].append(os.path.join(root, file))
#Execute code above then print(d) to make sure its ok before merging
for group, mergelist in d.items():
    #print(group, mergelist)
    arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=mergelist,
                           output=os.path.join(
                               outWorkspace, '{}0.shp'.format(group)))
```